# Is it possible to place a bandwidth limit on a Windows computer?

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, windows-10, bandwidth

On Linux I know you can install a specific module that will control the network adapter so you have a bandwidth control limit.

Is this possible on Windows as well? I was looking at the network driver options and network adapter settings but did not find anything.

In a business environment, I want to limit the amount of bandwidth each machine can use.

Comment: Windows does not have a built-in method for doing this (short of manually configuring the network adapter to connect to the network at a lower data rate).  If you wish to limit the bandwidth in a manner that affects the entire adapter, you're best off using an external device such as a router with bandwidth management controls.